# centos AWS shiny server wont resolve

Tags: r, centos, shiny, shiny-server

Set up using AWS instance running centOS 6.4 with R and shiny server using my Macbook and trying to figure out what is wrong with it as there are issues with this process

```
# set up AWS Redhat 6.4 instance (dont forget to download .pem)
# set the .pem file into your ~/.ssh/ folder and make sure you chmod the file
chmod 400 ~/.ssh/myshinypemexample.pem
```

## ssh into machine

```
ssh -i ~/.ssh/myshinypemexample.pem root@yourPublicDNS
# the first time you run this, just press yes, don't be scared :) 
# use ec2-user and log into machine
ssh -i ~/.ssh/myshinypemexample.pem ec2-user@yourPublicDNS
```

## Get the EPEL rpm

```
wget http://mirror.us.leaseweb.net/epel/6/i386/epel-release-6-8.noarch.rpm
rpm -ivh epel-release-6-8.noarch.rpm --test
```

## Import the EPEL GPG key

```
wget https://www.fedoraproject.org/static/0608B895.txt
sudo mv 0608B895.txt /etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-EPEL-6
sudo rpm --import /etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-EPEL-6
```

## Verify that the key has been imported.

```
rpm -qa gpg*
## You should see a line like this: gpg-pubkey-0608b895-4bd22942
```

## Install the rpm

```
sudo rpm -ivh epel-release-6-8.noarch.rpm
```

## Install shiny server

```
sudo su - -c "R -e \"install.packages('shiny', repos='http://cran.rstudio.com/')\""
 
# this gives error and have to install Rcpp and httr manually

    wget http://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Rcpp_0.11.1.tar.gz
    sudo R CMD INSTALL --build Rcpp_0.11.1.tar.gz
    wget http://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/httpuv_1.2.3.tar.gz
    sudo R CMD INSTALL --build httpuv_1.2.3.tar.gz
```

## run shiny server again

```
sudo su - -c "R -e \"install.packages('shiny', repos='http://cran.rstudio.com/')\""
```

## Install Shiny Server

```
wget http://download3.rstudio.org/centos-5.9/x86_64/shiny-server-1.0.0.42-x86_64.rpm
sudo yum install --nogpgcheck shiny-server-1.0.0.42-x86_64.rpm
 
# test server
sudo status shiny-server
```

## check location of example shiny app

```
sudo R -e "system.file('examples/01_hello', package='shiny')"
 
[1] "/usr/lib64/R/library/shiny/examples/01_hello"
 
#copy example file from R to /srv as Shiny looks for this location to work
sudo cp -R /usr/lib64/R/library/shiny/examples/01_hello /srv/shiny-server/
```

### MYIP:3838 does not resolve. Why?

Comment: Are you using the external IP of your instance? It's usually safer to use the DNS entry EC2 provides rather than try to guess at the IP unless you're explicitly using an elastic IP they provide.

Comment: Hi Jeff, yes I am, happy to share the IP, there is nothing on it that is unsafe to share as it is just a test instance at this stage. http://ec2-54-206-220-146.ap-southeast-2.compute.amazonaws.com:3838/ I have an Ubuntu version that I did the same thing for which works fine so unsure if I am making some silly rookie error here...

Comment: Is the machine in an EC2 security group that has port 3838 open?

Comment: Yes, currently ports 22, 80 and 3838 are all open

Comment: It seems that `shiny-server` isn't actually starting, then. You can check the log file in `/var/log/shiny-server.log`?

Comment: I see. When i ran status shiny-server it seems to be working. I checked the log, anything I should be looking for? I have 5 lines in there, 4 info and 1 with a warning about running as non root is better..

Comment: so I tried a couple of things but that didn't work. searching around, there is no server errors logged (eg// [ERROR] shiny-server – HTTP server error (0.0.0.0:3838) I found this googleing around, however, my set up does not have these errors logged. Is there a porting issue with centos using 3838? do i need to do something here as my set up went without a hitch, no errors yet i cant seem to get the example app to run and to be able to move forward with building to this server.. thanks :)

Comment: Why don't you just use an AMI that's already been set up by someone else?  I'm currently using this one, http://www.louisaslett.com/RStudio_AMI/ ...